# Inline JS webextension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making an extension for firefox/chrome however I'm running into a CSP problem.
Indeed my extension retrieves on a web page an array that contains a
`<a href="#" onclick="my_function('1234')">1234</a>`
I need this href to call my function with a variable, but I get the following error :

```
Content Security Policy: Les paramètres de la page ont empêché le chargement d’une ressource à inline (« script-src »).
```

I have put this on my manifest.json

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self; object-src 'self'",
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "config.js", "content.js"]
```

When I put `unsafe-inline`, I have this Chrome/Firefox say that `unsafe-inline` isn't support 
Thank for your help